# C++ - Count if on diagonal line

Tags: c++, stl

Is there any algorithms or approaches that offer a more efficient way to do the following? I'm thinking about using `std::count_if`.

Assume that I have a vector which contains:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > A = 
{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}
};
```

I just want to store all of the diagonal elements within this vector, i.e. `{1, 5, 9}` I can do this, using the traditional method of creating two loops `i, j` and having a condition `if(i == j)` but is there a better way?

Say I use `std::count_if`:

`std::count_if(std::begin(A), std::end(A), isDiagonalElement);`

Confusion: How would I be able to tell if the value is infact on the diagonal line?

Comment: `{1, 5, 6}` or `{1, 5, 9}`

Comment: do you want {3 , 5 , 7} as well?

Comment: why template parameter is `double`?

Comment: @Phorce What is the relation between "i want to store all of the diagonal elements" and algorithm std::count_if?

Comment: `std::count_if` with a stateful comparator (incrementing a counter internally to represent the horizontal movement) could work, but _only_ if elements are guaranteed to be visited in order, and I can find no such guarantee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

std:count_if with isDiagonal function will be slower than your implementation since it will iterate over all the elements whilst the manual implementation should only return one by one the required elements where ( i==k )

I dont think there can be any algorithms that are faster than that because basically, you need to visit the numbers you want to get at least for once to be able to get them. In any kind of copy operation you will need to iterate through required elements at least once.

So theoretically your manual algorithm of getting

```
matrix[0][0], matrix[1][1], matrix[2][2] ...
```

can not get any faster.

Answer (score 4):

I assume there's a typo and what you mean `{1, 5, 9}`. Why not use a single loop with accessing `a[i][i]`?